# Is there any way to access GSM modem from a remote machine

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have an application built in asp.net , csharp which sends **SMS alerts by using AT commands** on the serial interface of the GSM hardware.
So far everything is working fine as the modem is physically plugged to the machine.
We are deploying the application on a remote machine on which the GSM can't be plugged physically.

Is there any way to access the GSM modem on the machine placed remotely if i assigned it a live IP ?

Answer (score 2):

GSM modem does not get ATCommands on IP. You need to access the COM port to send commands to GSM modem. You can Run a windows service/Application/Web service where you will send your message and that will be send to modem through windows service/Application/Web service.

A webservice could be a solution. As you have already Developed an application to work with GSM modem you need to call a web service that may have code to talk to modem or can pass message to your existing application.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [**com0com**](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/) project on sourceforge. It provides virtual COM ports and with the sub-project [**hub4com**](http://com0com.cvs.sourceforge.net/%2acheckout%2a/com0com/hub4com/ReadMe.txt?revision=RELEASED) it even allows you to tunnel COM communication via TCP/IP.